# Why Google Chrome crashes when trying to print a grid view data?

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, printing

I am trying to print my grid view data(with 50 records), in my web application. It's working perfect in Internet Explorer. But when it comes to Google Chrome, chrome itself crashes. Herewith I given my coding for printing the grid view data.

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
gviewEmployeeTimesheet.RenderControl(hw);
string gridHTML = sw.ToString().Replace("\"", "'").Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>");
sb.Append("window.onload = new function(){");
sb.Append("var printWin = window.open('', '', 'left=0");
sb.Append(",top=0,width=1000,height=600,status=0');");
sb.Append("printWin.document.write(\"");
sb.Append(gridHTML);
sb.Append("\");");
sb.Append("printWin.document.close();");
sb.Append("printWin.focus();");
sb.Append("printWin.print();");
sb.Append("printWin.close();};");
sb.Append("</script>");
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "GridPrint", sb.ToString());
```

Can any one help me to get rid of this?

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Have you tried printing the page without opening it in a popup window? Or just opening the popup window without the print? Remove as many variables from the equation to try and isolate what is causing it.

Comment: Yes @StevenVondruska, I have tried. But it crashes again.

Comment: Try changing your HTML from what your rendering to a simple `<p>` tag? You may have found a Chrome bug, but without figuring out what is throwing it for a loop, the bug report will be useless. [Chrome Crash Reporting Guidelines](http://dev.chromium.org/for-testers/bug-reporting-guidelines/reporting-crash-bug)

Answer (score 0):

2 Ideas:

1. Check your HTML and JavaScript with a validator. Surround it with `<html></body>...</body></html>`
2. Split up your gridHTML into smaller chunks. Maybe the string is just too long.